# Site for questions about ultrasound

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for the right Stack Exchange site, or tag on a specific site, that deals with ultrasound and its many applications. Some of the topics I am interested in knowing about are

- ultrasound physics basics
- ultrasound simulation software (preferrably open source)
- ultrasound applications in

  - medicine - diagnostic and therapeutic
  - non destructive testing of materials (NDT)
- ultrasound signal processing

I understand most of the topics I have mentioned can be found in [separate
topics](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=ultrasound) such as DSP, image
processing, etc., but I'd like to know if such a specific site/tag exists or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ultrasound physics basics

Try [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), which has [questions on various ultrasound applications and how they work](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=ultrasound). [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) is not a good choice; [engineering is off-topic there](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535/56299).

> ultrasound applications in
>
> - medicine - diagnostic and therapeutic
> - non destructive testing of materials (NDT)

For the former, [Health Stack Exchange](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions)
is a good choice; for the latter, I think Engineering is your best bet. Health has a [ultrasounds](/questions/tagged/ultrasounds) [tag](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultrasounds) and a [transvaginal-ultrasound](/questions/tagged/transvaginal-ultrasound) [tag](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transvaginal-ultrasound).

> ultrasound signal processing

I want to suggest [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), which indeed has an [ultrasound](/questions/tagged/ultrasound) [tag](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultrasound), but I don't know their scope that well.